# Special considerations when designing a PCB with signals in HF band (3 -30 MHz)

Tags: pcb-design, hf

I want to design a PCB which will handle RF signals in the HF band (3 -30 MHz).

Are there any special considerations when designing a PCB at these frequencies?

I know higher frequency PCBs require special design considerations due to transmission line effects, but I am not expecting any of these effects due to the large wavelength of the signal compared to the small size of the PCB.

In the past I have only designed PCBs for low frequencies and mainly digital signals, and I have never had to deal with the integrity of high frequency analog signals and oscillators.

Any recommendations will be much appreciated. My goal is to have the PCB work the first time because I have a low budget and limited time.

Comment: What frequency was the clock on the digital board you designed and, what PCB techniques did you employ?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with RF signals? Analog signals in general require special attention regardless of frequency, but what you need to do depends on the application.

Comment: There are books written about this subject, I recommend checking out Eric Bogatin and Rick Hartley's books/videos for some additional insight.

Comment: @Andyaka I have only designed boards for signals up to a couple MHz. I keep in mind the basic recommendations like reducing loop area, keeping signal paths distant and maintaining ground plane integrity, but I am wondering if there are any additional considerations when working at HF or if any of the usual considerations becomes particularly important.

Comment: @Ryan I am building an RC car from scratch. I am planning to use wireless digital communications with a carrier frequency of 27.12 MHz. This involves constructing a digital modulator, filters and amplifiers designed to work at that frequency.

Comment: @JYelton I love everything published by Eric Bogatinand I will definitely check out Rick Hartley. The main issue I am having is that the HF band is neither here nor there in the sense that it's definitely not a high enough frequency for many of the issues pointed out by Eric Bogatin, but I have a hunch it  also won't behave as a LF PCB. I am interested to know what considerations are valid and what precautions I have to take when working in this frequency band.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing analog circuitry has everything to do with maximizing SNR. There are two ways to do this:

1. Increase the signal power
2. Decrease the noise power

In a communications system, both techniques are used, but it’s worth noting that amplifying the signal will also amplify the noise that is already in that signal. That is why it is usually best to add any amplification early on in the receiver before more noise gets induced (like an LNA).

Now there are many many techniques and considerations to make to reduce noise in an analog signal. There are entire books about this kind of stuff, but here’s a few basics:

1. Use components with high CMRR, high PSRR, and low noise.
2. Keep traces as short as possible to reduce the total length of the trace that can be affected by radiated EMI. This also reduces attenuation that can occur from the resistance of the trace.
3. Keep analog traces far away from other traces and planes to reduce the effects of radiated EMI.
4. Keep return paths for analog and digital signals separated (full isolation or split planes are not necessary, but the latter can help you make sure you’re keeping them separated).